Extract text using llama3.1
I'm new to llama and prompting in general, and would appreciate some help here.
Basically I am trying to use llama (8B with ollama) to extract a section from a long text. I used a prompt like this one:

I have a long document, and I need to extract a specific section titled ‘Introduction’. Please locate the section in the text that starts with the heading ‘Introduction’ and provide the entire content of this section until the next heading or until the end of the document. If the section isn’t found, indicate that as well.

However, llama didn't seem to follow the prompt, and I kept on getting a section-by-section summary of the text. The same prompt seems to be working as expected on gpt-4o. Any suggestions on what might be wrong? (The text fits into the context window, and I set temperature at 0) Appreciate any suggestions or pointers here.

What's the format of your source file? This task should be done in a few lines of script if the file is text. Don't see any reason why you would use a llm.

The format is 'dirty' html. Since the documents could be different authors, they could have different formats or wording. E.g. one person could be using 'I. Introduction', and another person could be using '1. Introduction '. With different regex combination, I was able to get ~40% of the docs parsed. It seems to me that the task might be difficult for a 'formatting'-based parser, but should be obvious for a 'meaning' based one; therefore I'm exploring the LLM route. I'm complete noob to LLM, so would appreciate any insights here.

Others have noted issues with the Ollama distribution of llama3.1 8B, see this issue for updates. In particular, the problem arises with longer inputs, with speculation the issue may be with RoPE scaling. It’s impossible to say if this is the basis of your issues without more details. You could try other ways to access the model which may be configured differently, such as groq.
Of course, you wouldn’t expect an 8B model to perform as well as 4o, but it should suffice for your simple task.

Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and the insights here!
